# kube-apiserver is gone

Tags: kubernetes

System details:

- Kubernetes version: 1.20.1
- Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I have started it today my Kubernetes Lab (on VirtualBox)
and any `kubectl` command ends up like this:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
The connection to the server master:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces
The connection to the server master:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Indeed, there is nothing listening on socket master:6443:

```
$ ss -tl4np
State                           Recv-Q                          Send-Q                                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port                          Process
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:34627                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:10248                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                       192.168.1.190:2379                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:2379                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                       192.168.1.190:2380                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:2381                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:33133                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:10257                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                           127.0.0.1:10259                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               4096                                                       127.0.0.53%lo:53                                                             0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                          0                               128                                                              0.0.0.0:22                                                             0.0.0.0:*

ccd@master:~$ curl https://master:6443
curl: (7) Failed to connect to master port 6443: Connection refused
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I start kube-apiserver?
2. Why all of the sudden is kube-apiserver gone? 
   It was working quite well last time I was this lab.

Side note: kubelet service is running but is in error state.

```
Jan 17 20:40:43 master kubelet[613]: E0117 20:40:43.451465     613 kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node \"master\" not found"
Jan 17 20:40:43 master kubelet[613]: E0117 20:40:43.552175     613 kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node \"master\" not found"
```

**[UPDATE]**

It seems that in my lab kube-apiserver is running as docker container:

```
root@master:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
0adc676e6077   595f327f224a           "kube-scheduler --au…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_7
8e5200bd131f   25f8c7f3da61           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_etcd_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_7
7ad4134212ce   df7b72818ad2           "kube-controller-man…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_7
6baca0741b74   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_POD_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_7
9a5572813b8a   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_7
daca7dae837c   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_7
10871d3a6e66   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-master_kube-system_01ecc291decf2feb7dae990cc7eb8cb6_7
```

In the COMMAND column it says "/pause". 
I tried to unpause it, but no luck.  :(

```
root@master:~# docker unpause 10871d3a6e66
Error response from daemon: Container 10871d3a6e66c897af6cfa33ea4c45668045ab15bb29beab938556937589e3ad is not paused
```

The `docker logs 10871d3a6e66` command reports:

```
Shutting down, got signal: Terminated
```

**[UPDATE]**
I can actually see kube-apiserver trying to startup BUT it seems to be crashing every time it tries. See the first container on the list.

```
    $ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
bed0b4e9170c   8fa62c12256d           "kube-apiserver --ad…"   39 seconds ago   Exited (1) 14 seconds ago             k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-master_kube-system_01ecc291decf2feb7dae990cc7eb8cb6_9
fda323106b5f   25f8c7f3da61           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   7 minutes ago    Up 7 minutes                          k8s_etcd_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_4
a05557b1d66b   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 7 minutes ago    Up 7 minutes                          k8s_POD_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_4
0befad0f3003   df7b72818ad2           "kube-controller-man…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                          k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_4
8f3b2a3756a9   595f327f224a           "kube-scheduler --au…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                          k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_4
3aeb39d118d3   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                          k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_4
8b0c53496168   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                          k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_4
bd5f13dee325   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                          k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-master_kube-system_01ecc291decf2feb7dae990cc7eb8cb6_4
6c081ae55883   fd1608dbbc19           "start_runit"            9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_calico-node_calico-node-q5cpc_kube-system_27708358-127b-4078-9b42-e4953190ed80_3
d5acca3521c4   a4ca41631cc7           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_coredns_coredns-64897985d-rmgtq_kube-system_2e772c34-7c77-4862-bab0-93be9f371095_3
4b3b0dca6679   a1a88662416b           "/usr/bin/kube-contr…"   9 months ago     Exited (2) 9 months ago               k8s_calico-kube-controllers_calico-kube-controllers-7c845d499-95nlh_kube-system_bbb4637d-e143-46e5-97df-4ebc36c455b3_3
428d125b24d9   a4ca41631cc7           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_coredns_coredns-64897985d-dwrpn_kube-system_5492f4f3-cc4d-4461-b57f-bb03f8fbc6a2_3
78a0ecbd465b   d6660bf471e1           "/usr/local/bin/flex…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_flexvol-driver_calico-node-q5cpc_kube-system_27708358-127b-4078-9b42-e4953190ed80_0
03a6837fc5bd   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_calico-kube-controllers-7c845d499-95nlh_kube-system_bbb4637d-e143-46e5-97df-4ebc36c455b3_12
da8ae7c12d4f   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_coredns-64897985d-rmgtq_kube-system_2e772c34-7c77-4862-bab0-93be9f371095_12
c6afacd9d088   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_coredns-64897985d-dwrpn_kube-system_5492f4f3-cc4d-4461-b57f-bb03f8fbc6a2_12
cbdcedf7183a   be7dfc21ba2e           "/opt/cni/bin/install"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_install-cni_calico-node-q5cpc_kube-system_27708358-127b-4078-9b42-e4953190ed80_0
0d1c5aeee222   be7dfc21ba2e           "/opt/cni/bin/calico…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_upgrade-ipam_calico-node-q5cpc_kube-system_27708358-127b-4078-9b42-e4953190ed80_1
d5c211817c38   4c0375452406           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   9 months ago     Exited (2) 9 months ago               k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-dmhv4_kube-system_ae5b3e51-be54-41d0-8aeb-4049756a0e0a_3
27534d78c56f   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_calico-node-q5cpc_kube-system_27708358-127b-4078-9b42-e4953190ed80_3
95876ad85c66   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_kube-proxy-dmhv4_kube-system_ae5b3e51-be54-41d0-8aeb-4049756a0e0a_3
ba442d9c0cb0   595f327f224a           "kube-scheduler --au…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_3
14cc628ce7ee   df7b72818ad2           "kube-controller-man…"   9 months ago     Exited (2) 9 months ago               k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_3
7aca9140ee03   25f8c7f3da61           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_etcd_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_3
f220f955a404   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-master_kube-system_172567758300a3c99b36d0d4efd9321a_3
c16d35dba1fb   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_etcd-master_kube-system_dd8c7aeab8fa24c31e933da39dcafd96_3
80e581f9529c   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 9 months ago     Exited (0) 9 months ago               k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-master_kube-system_b38aa758e725e1c490cee42d42ec8bff_3
8cc54605041f   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 21 months ago    Exited (0) 21 months ago              k8s_POD_coredns-64897985d-dwrpn_kube-system_5492f4f3-cc4d-4461-b57f-bb03f8fbc6a2_11
666788dcedf5   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 21 months ago    Exited (0) 21 months ago              k8s_POD_calico-kube-controllers-7c845d499-95nlh_kube-system_bbb4637d-e143-46e5-97df-4ebc36c455b3_11
84046839fc1b   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6   "/pause"                 21 months ago    Exited (0) 21 months ago              k8s_POD_coredns-64897985d-rmgtq_kube-system_2e772c34-7c77-4862-bab0-93be9f371095_11
```

I also tried to run it manually like this but that didnt work:

```
$ sudo docker run -it 8fa62c12256d
2024/01/22 12:57:56 not enough arguments to run
```

**[WORKAROUND]**

I could not find any solution for my problem.
As this is just my VirtualBox LAB system (and **I do not mind the data/projects to lose**), I have re-initiated it (cluster).

1. Reset master node:

```
sudo su -
kubeadm reset -f
rm -rf /etc/cni /etc/kubernetes /var/lib/dockershim /var/lib/etcd /var/lib/kubelet /var/run/kubernetes ~/.kube/*

iptables -F && iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t raw -F && iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -t mangle -X

systemctl restart docker

exit
rm -rf ~/.kube/*
```

2. Run kubeadm init

```
sudo kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --control-plane-endpoint master:6443 --pod-network-cidr 10.10.0.0/16
```

3. Add certificates ($HOME/.kube/config)

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

4. Apply CNI (in my case calico)

```
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml

kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
master   Ready    control-plane,master   29m   v1.23.4
```

Node/Worker:

1. Make sure to have master entry in /etc/hosts
2. Re-join the node:

```
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo kubeadm join master:6443 --token aaaaaa.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \
        --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: If I had to guess, pod constraints are shutting it down due to limited resources. Please add to the question how much CPU and RAM your VM has, and the output of the free command.

Comment: Why also such an old k8s version? 1.27.1 is out, which btw, uses containerd